# Yii2 - Generating CRUD from all models

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, gii

After creating all database tables in MySQL or MariaDB, I am able to generate all Yii2 Models using gii by simple entering * and voila, all models are created.

My question; I was wondering if there's an equivalent way of generating all CRUD - at once - based on generated models in a similar way, either from the console with a one-liner or from the browser with the gii CRUD Generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

Not using standard "yiisoft/yii2-gii" unfortunately. You can compare the "generate()" functions for the model and crud to get a programmatic reason here:

Model: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/src/generators/model/Generator.php

CRUD: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/src/generators/crud/Generator.php

---

Solution:

- You can use "schmunk42/yii2-giiant" which looks to do what you require and has decent decent support. Found here: https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant
- "mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii" is another option but was last updated August 2017. Found here: https://github.com/mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii

I hope these help.

Comment: Thanks, seems like yii2-giiant is what I am looking.